# How to create a map with mappings in single statement

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to create an empty map in java 8, then put some keys and values in it all at once. Is this possible? I have included code of what I want to do.

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("candy" "chocolate", "shoes", "sneakers", "car", "prius");
```

Comment: it's lazy and less readable. don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Java 8, you can do it like this.

```
new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("Key-1", "Value-1");
        put("Key-2", "Value-2");
    }
};
```

In case of Google Guava, you can do it like this.

```
ImmutableMap.of("Key-1", "Value-1", "Key-2", "Value-2");
```

Comment: And, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/5699679) for why you should not use so-called "double brace initialization".

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your information. I really like it.

Comment: that not a hashmap, that an anonymous innerclass subclass of hashmap, most likely no longer serializable.

Comment: Using your first example is a bad idea, as it creates an anonymous class that can hold a reference to an enclosing instance, it can lead to unintended and unexpected memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you Sir for pointing this concept, I got to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you do not have access to Java9+ and can use an outside library, you can use apache MapUtils `putAll`, docs found [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#putAll-java.util.Map-java.lang.Object:A-):

> public static  Map putAll(Map map,
>                                       Object[] array)
>
> "Puts all the keys and values from the specified array into the map."

Example from docs:

```
 Map colorMap = MapUtils.putAll(new HashMap(), new String[] {
 "RED", "#FF0000",
 "GREEN", "#00FF00",
 "BLUE", "#0000FF"
 });
```